# How to get all unread emails in JAVA from lotus notes domino server

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am new to Notes JAVA API and developing a utility where I require to read all unread mails from a Lotus notes id.Now when i try to use **lotus.domino.Database.getAllUnreadDocuments()** it gives me the following exception

```
NotesException: Not implemented
at lotus.domino.cso.Base.notImplemented(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.Document.markRead(Unknown Source)
at com.email.ReadEmailRemotely.readEmails(ReadEmailRemotely.java:428)
at com.email.ReadEmailRemotely.run(ReadEmailRemotely.java:96)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My application is a plain JAVA application in eclipse using NCSO.jar

My question is , **do i need to extend lotus.domino.AgentBase ?**

If yes then what all dependencies do i require as , JAVA app is not allowing to extend it.
& if no then is there any other way to get all unread mails?

Comment: Does Lotus Domino support IMAP?

Comment: Ondra, it does but require that the server has been set up to offer it.

Comment: I can see that there's is a bug report for the "not implemented" situation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1LO63818

Comment: thnx for quick reply.please refer below comment.

Comment: Is there any work around that i can use?

Comment: AgentBase is for code that runs as a Notes or Domino agent, either within the Notes client's JVM or withing the Domino server's JVM.  Standalone Java apps do not extend AgentBase.

Comment: Can you show us some code, @user1945321?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way (assuming you are can edit the NSF) is to create a hidden view which lists only the documents you want to get back.

Then access that view and iterate through it.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to set the selection formula for a view to include only unread docs.

Comment: Thanx Simon,I am following a similar approach .After reading the mails I put them into a predefined folder and then remove it from the inbox.But the issue is that when i remove it from inbox it gets deleted from my predefined folder also.Is there any way that i can remove it from inbox only?

Comment: @user1945321 - To remove a document from a folder use the method NotesDocument.RemoveFromFolder("$Inbox"). NotesDocument.Remove() actually deletes the document from the database and all folders in which you put it.

Answer (score 0):

If the server supports IMAP or POP3, you can use JavaMail API, which is pretty easy and has a flag for unread messages.

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("myserver.com", "user", "pass");

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
            Message messages[] = inbox.search(ft);
     }
```

Comment: Lotus Domino does not support IMAP or POP3.Not sure which one but Lotus Notes implements its own protocol and they provide a Notes JAVA API to access their mails.The problem is most of the methods are unimpemented in NCSO.jar which after googling i found out requires an AgentBase.And I have no clue of AgentBase.

Comment: That is incorrect.  Lotus Domino has supported IMAP and POP3 for many years. The primary protocol is NRPC, but IMAP, POP3, HTTP, IIOP (whihc is what NCSO.jar uses) and probably a few others I'm not thinking of are all supported.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to switch to using notes.jar instead of ncso.jar.

In order to use notes.jar and access the getAllUnreadDocuments method, you will need to install Notes and Domino 8 or above on the system where your code is running.

Comment: I checked the APAR @PerHenrikLausten mentions above. The method call is not implemented at all in NCSO.jar or NOTES.jar.

Comment: In that case, the only possible way would be to develop a web service or agent in LotusScript that gets the collection of unread docs and returns a list of NoteIds, and have the Java code invoke this code to get the answer.

Comment: BTW: There is doc for the method that implies it exists in the Java classes.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_GETALLUNREADDOCUMENTS_DATABASE.html  I don't know if the APAR mentions that.

Comment: Yep. the SPR for that APAR is to either implement or update documentation. :)

Comment: If at all it is implemented in NOTES.jar , I will not be allowed to switch to it as I have to access the DOMINO server remotely only.

Comment: Also the notes java api suggest that getAllUnreadDocuments method does exist ,it is not implemented in NCSO.jar . This is a defect as mentioned by Per Henrik Lausten check http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1LO63818

Answer (score 0):

May require Secure Connection(SSL), Use the following properties to connect mail server supporting POP3 protocol:

```
        properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "POP3_PORT");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", "POP3_SERVER_HOST_NAME_OR_IP");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```